# Lenovo Legion 5 keyboard backlight malfunctioning with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, suspend, ubuntu-drivers, keyboard-backlight

I have recently switched to ubuntu 22.04 LTS in my Lenovo legion 5 ( dual booted along with windows 11 ). I am facing an issue with the keyboard backlight, the computer automatically turns on the keyboard backlight when it is awakening from sleep mode. This has happened multiple times and I couldn't find any reason or solution for fixing the problem online. Please help. Thank you

I have checked for the proper installation of keyboard drives and it shows no issues. I don't know if there are any other possible reasons for this problem. I would like to get a fix for this. I don't know if there are any other ubuntu users facing the same issue with the latest (22.04 LTS ) version of Ubuntu.